# Table with the logarithmic step

Tags: syntax, list-manipulation, logarithmic-scale

Suppose some function y[x]. I need to calculate the table of the value of this function with the logarithmic step of the coordinate, i.e., the operation which corresponds to the Mathematica's command LogPlot. Could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: It would be useful to add code you have tried e.g. defining a representative `y[x]`,step size and range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
f[x_] := x^2;
With[{x := 10^xp}, Table[{x, f[x]}, {xp, 0, 5}]]
```

> {{1, 1}, {10, 100}, {100, 10000}, {1000, 1000000}, {10000, 100000000}, {100000, 10000000000}}

Comment: It seems that this is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Or, for simplicity/brevity, `{10^#, f[10^#]} & /@ Range[0, 5]` would get the same result.