# Use the Table command with growing steps. Is it possible?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, distributions

Is it possible to use the Table function with growing steps? In other words, as the function proceeds it takes larger steps.

The intention is to have a set of data with unequal distribution in which it has more density in the beginning and as it reaches the end the time steps become larger. Imagine something like this figure.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a function to generate those steps?

Comment: It only depends on the function which you use inside Table, as in `Table[func, {i,imax}]`. What kind of function/distribution do you need?

Comment: If you know the dicretisation, you might use `Table[...,{x,{x0,x1,...,xn}}]`

Comment: `f[x_] = 5 x;

ListLinePlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 2^Range[-1, 5]}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: @TheoTiger This is actually a part of my question. I need a nonlinear distribution

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. That was a good suggestion. I think something like exponential growth would fulfill my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adopting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157288/table-with-the-logarithmic-step) @ChrisK idea.

```
f[x_] := x;

da = With[{x := E^xp - 1}, Table[{x, f[x]}, {xp, 0, 5}]]

ListLinePlot[da, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[da]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! thats it.